# MVVM - Handling operations that need to be performed on an underlying Model that a ViewModel represents

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating a small application that is more or less a personal training app for MVVM. In my application, I have a `ListView` whose `ItemsSource` property is bound to an `ObservableCollection<PetViewModel>`. Each `PetViewModel` represents the actual `Pet` Model/object.

The `ListViewItems`, which are `PetViewModel` objects, can be selected, and then the `Pet` can be purchased. My question is, what is the usual way to handle this type of situation where we don't want the `PetViewModel` to be purchased, but the actual Pet that it represents?

Let me elaborate: I want to purchase a pet, so I select a `ListViewItem` (`PetViewModel`) and click the Purchase button. I then want to record the purchase (in this case via an `Order` object), and the `Order` will be stored in some type of database, such as an XML file. Is it good/common practice to have the `Pet` model be a property of the `PetViewModel`, and then I can just access the `Pet` model through the `PetViewModel` when saving these objects to a database?

Example code of creating the order might be:

```
Order o = new Order();
o.Customer = GetCurrentCustomer();
o.PurchasedPet = petViewModel.Pet;
SaveOrderToDatabase(o);
```

Is this perfectly acceptable MVVM or is there a better method of handling operations on the underlying Model that a ViewModel represents?

Note: This is NOT specific to my application. It's a general question regarding MVVM. I'm using my application as a specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends.

In your scenario, it sounds like your `PetViewModel` could easily have an `OrderCommand` (`ICommand`) on it, and handle the logic for the ordering itself.  This avoids needing to expose the underlying model as a public property, as the VM would handle all of this "application specific" logic directly.

Comment: What happens if I allow selecting multiple `PetViewModel` and need to include 2 (or more) purchased pets in one order?

Comment: @xCrispy In that case, you'd probably want the main VM to handle the command - but you could still route it through a method on the individual `PetViewModel`, or expose the `Pet` - it really just depends on what seems to be the most clean in your scenario.

Comment: So what would be the best way of routing it through the `PetViewModel`? Would I create the order in the main VM and then send the order over to each selected `PetViewModel` and allow each one to add its underlying `Pet` to the order?

Comment: @xCrispy Again, depends on your scenario.  Having a method to add to an order seems reasonable - though I don't mind exposing the model, either, if that's simpler.